# use DOMXPath and function query php

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

Have the following html code section:

```
<ul id="tree">
  <li>
    <a href="">first</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">subfirst</a></li>
      <li><a href="">subsecond</a></li>
      <li><a href="">subthird</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">second</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">subfirst</a></li>
      <li><a href="">subsecond</a></li>
      <li><a href="">subthird</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Need parse this html code and get next (using DOMXPath::query() and foreach())

```
- first
-- subfirst
-- subsecond
-- subthird
- second
-- subfirst
-- subsecond
-- subthird
```

Piece of code:

```
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($html);
$catgs = $xpath->query('//*[@id="tree"]/li/a');
foreach ($catgs as $category) {
  // first level
  echo '- ' . mb_strtolower($category->nodeValue) . '<br>';

  // second level
  // don't know
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to include details of the code you have so far, and the problem you are having, including full text of any error message or unexpected output.

Comment: Please edit your attempts in your questions. And give the community a clear overview why this didn't work for you and where you are stuck in specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what DOMBLAZE is for:

```
/* DOMBLAZE */ $doc->registerNodeClass("DOMElement","DOMBLAZE"); class DOMBLAZE extends DOMElement{public function __invoke($expression) {return $this->xpath($expression);} function xpath($expression){$result=(new DOMXPath($this->ownerDocument))->evaluate($expression,$this);return($result instanceof DOMNodeList)?new IteratorIterator($result):$result;}}

$list = $doc->getElementById('tree');

foreach ($list('./li') as $item) {
    echo '- ', $item('string(./a)'), "\n";
    foreach ($item('./ul/li') as $subitem) {
        echo '-- ', $subitem('string(./a)'), "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
- first
-- subfirst
-- subsecond
-- subthird
- second
-- subfirst
-- subsecond
-- subthird
```

*DOMBLAZE* is [FluentDOM](https://github.com/ThomasWeinert/FluentDOM) for the poor.

Answer (score 2):

For the second level, you could use another query also:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($markup);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//ul[@id="tree"]/li');
foreach($elements as $el) {
    $head = $xpath->query('./a', $el)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo "- $head <br/>";
    foreach($xpath->query('./ul/li/a', $el) as $sub) { // query the second level
        echo '-- ' . $sub->nodeValue . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

[example out](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QvJM8T)